# Ethernet over powerline adapters - how far will the data travel?

Tags: networking, security

I would like to get a pair of [Ethernet over powerline adapters](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ethernet%20power%20adapters&oq=ethernet%20power%20adapters#q=ethernet%20power%20adapters&tbm=shop) so I can get a better connection on my desktop than what I currently get over WiFi.

My problem is that I live in a block of flats. I'm not sure if this will share my LAN throughout the whole building, or just my flat. Can someone shed some light whether this is an issue or not?

A colleague said you can encrypt the traffic, and I could probably setup my router to only allow certain MAC addresses. But I still don't like the idea of sharing my connection throughout the whole building.

Comment: It's only work if they are on the same wire/circuit.

Comment: This is not true, it's dependent on phases, which means in theory, your neighbor could pick up your information.

Comment: @techie007, From what I understand, that is only true with early powerline gear as they were not capable of working across two phases (due to being conducted signals), but newer gear uses radiated signals and can work across 220/240v phases and therefore aren't limited to a single circuit.

Comment: AFAIK, these devices work by being `paired`. One of your neighbors couldn't `pair` with you without you taking action to allow the `pairing`.

Comment: @DanielChateau, that isn't quite the case, but it depends on the infrastructure. In an apartment complex that may be the case. Even though it can cross phases and circuits, it isn't capable of crossing transformers, so if you live in a house, your next door neighbors won't be able to pick it up.

Comment: *"But I still don't like the idea of sharing my connection throughout the whole building"* -- Then why do you use 802.11, which broadcasts the WiFi signal throughout your building and beyond?  You already have a security problem.  You're just replacing one security problem with another security problem.

Comment: Beware that your [Ethernet power adapters](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ethernet%20power%20adapters&oq=ethernet%20power%20adapters#q=ethernet%20power%20adapters&tbm=shop) link is a mix of **PoE** (Power over Ethernet) and **Ethernet over power**, aka Powerline Ethernet.  Hope you understand the difference.

Comment: @sawdust That's a very good point. I didn't think about it like that. And thanks for pointing out the differences.

Comment: All **Ethernet over Power** devices I have seen in the las 4 years have the possibility of encrypting network communications. They do even request for a password for connecting a new MAC to your network.

Comment: From experience I'd also suggest on standardising on one standard - I'm currently running all 500 mbps gear, though my initial network was 200 mbps. It makes it easier to work out whether the bottleneck is your gear or the network, especially if you have gear that will accept a gig-e ethernet connection.

Comment: I'd also add, referring to them as homeplug AV in searches would avoid the confusion - most of these units are branded as such

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe (and have made an edit to your post) that you actually mean an Ethernet over powerline bridge. These are a fancy set of circuitry that ultimately act as a very long Ethernet cable.

How far it works is dependent on a few factors that ultimately require a combination of testing and test equipment. **The most straightforward way to try it out would be to visit a neighbor and plug it in directly to see if you can get a connection in their flat.**

As others have mentioned in comments, it's normal for these devices to be simple bridge type adapters that require a pairing procedure of some sort. Once paired, these devices will only communicate with each paired device, not with unpaired devices that appear. You can look for specific models of adapters that include built-in security, [such as these TP-LINK ones](http://www.tp-link.com/lk/products/details/?categoryid=1658&model=TL-PA4030KIT).

Comment: I like the TP-Link ones - most of these devices come with cross compatible software, and theirs was the nicest I've used so far. I use it with my aztech adaptors too.

Answer (score 4):

Referencing this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/330668/10165) - Its supposed to stop at your power meter - I do believe the connection between the mains and power lines is coupled, rather than a physical connection, which allows this. The theoretical range is 300 meters, but practically, this is the length of your *power lines*, and homeplug is a sensitive to line noise, so it will be less.

Every homeplug adaptor I've bought has had a standard pre-set private network name and adaptors on the same power line with *different* network names don't talk to each other. I'd strongly recommend resetting these to something, since if nothing else, it helps you troubleshoot. Once this is done, you will not be sharing your connection with a non-paired adaptor in your *apartment* let alone the whole building.

I'd also add, I never picked up anyone elses network when I ran homeplug, and I'm sure at least one of the ~90 apartments other than mine has at least experimented with it ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the connection will travel farther then you think - have a look [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9725/are-powerline-ethernet-adapters-inherently-secure) to see the comments relating to these devices travelling across meters and phases of wiring.

This is not to say you can't encrypt your signals, only that they may well travel through to other flats.

Answer (score 0):

If you connect your routers internet port or WAN port to the line that goes out to the internet and you place all of your devices on the LAN (internal ports) or even a wireless LAN behind the router, you should be safe as long as you stick to an encrypted Wi-Fi connection, if you decide to go wireless.

The router is your hardware firewall, as long as you keep your devices connected to the LAN side of the router and don't DMZ them, they will be safe. I don't know if you want to send a Wi-Fi signal a long distance but a company called Ubiquiti makes some great long range access points, no need to use power line Ethernet, it is slow and from what I have read, it has many draw backs to it. [Ubiquiti website](http://ubnt.com)

If you want to confirm you are on your own LAN, turn on file and print sharing and allow the necessary ports to open in the software firewall. If you don't see any unknown PCs that aren't yours in your network, that should confirm you are on your own LAN. You can also download a program called netscan.exe from this website [Netscan download site](http://www.softperfect.com/products/networkscanner/). With this tool you can set the IP range of your network and scan to see, what other devices are found on it. You should only see your won devices

I hope this helps out
Cheers